# How to customize arrow buttons in Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

How can I customize the arrow buttons below from [swipers](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WXt1ZXbytFQ)?

```
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
```

I did it crudely but it does not seem to be the right way because I get some margin on the right of the button.

```
<div class="swiper-button-next hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only" style="border: 1px solid red; background-color: yellow; padding: 30px; ></div>
```

The entire code:

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide {
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.swiper-banner-slide {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.swiper-slide .title {
  font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
  font-size: 41px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.swiper-slide .subtitle {
  font-size: 21px;
}

.swiper-slide .text {
  font-size: 21px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.slide-info-container {
  color: #000;
}

.swiper-block {
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  /*padding: 0;*/
}

.swiper-block .swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.swiper-block .swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Zurb - CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- Swiper - CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>

  <div class="row" id="banner">

    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpg')">

          <!-- grid container -->
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
              <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 cell slide-info-container">
                <h3 class="title">Aliquam dictum mattis velit 1</h3>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo. Integer laoreet magna nec elit suscipit, ac laoreet nibh euismod. </p>
                </div>
                <a href="#features" class="hollow button button-details">More Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- grid container -->

        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide" style="background-image: url('images/2.jpg')">

          <!-- grid container -->
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
              <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 cell slide-info-container">
                <h3 class="title">Aliquam dictum mattis velit 2</h3>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Aliquam hendrerit lorem at elit facilisis rutrum. Ut at ullamcorper velit. Nulla ligula nisi, imperdiet ut lacinia nec, tincidunt ut libero. Aenean feugiat non eros quis feugiat.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#features" class="hollow button button-details">More Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- grid container -->

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide" style="background-image: url('images/3.jpg')">

          <!-- grid container -->
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
              <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 cell slide-info-container">
                <h3 class="title">Aliquam dictum mattis velit 3</h3>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. </p>
                </div>
                <a href="#features" class="hollow button button-details">More Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- grid container -->

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide" style="background-image: url('images/4.jpg')">

          <!-- grid container -->
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
              <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 cell slide-info-container">
                <h3 class="title">Aliquam dictum mattis velit 4</h3>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dictum mattis velit, sit amet faucibus felis iaculis nec. Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. </p>
                </div>
                <a href="#features" class="hollow button button-details">More Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- grid container -->

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-banner-slide" style="background-image: url('images/5.jpg')">

          <!-- grid container -->
          <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
              <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 cell slide-info-container">
                <h3 class="title">Aliquam dictum mattis velit 5</h3>
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Nulla laoreet justo vitae porttitor porttitor. Suspendisse in sem justo.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#features" class="hollow button button-details">More Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- grid container -->

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only" style="border: 1px solid red; background-color: yellow; padding: 30px; ></div>
        <div class=" swiper-button-prev hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only "></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Swiper -->

    </div>

    <!-- row block -->
    <div class="row swiper-block ">

        <div class="grid-container ">
            <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x ">

                <div class="small-12 cell ">
                    <!-- Swiper -->
                    <div class="swiper-container ">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper ">
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 1</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 2</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 3</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 4</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 5</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 6</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 7</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 8</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 9</div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">Slide 10</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Add Pagination -->
                        <div class="swiper-pagination "></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</main>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).foundation();

    var swiper = new Swiper('#banner .swiper-container', {
        pagination: '#banner .swiper-pagination',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        keyboardControl: true,
        nextButton: '#banner .swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '#banner .swiper-button-prev',
    });


    var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-block .swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-block .swiper-pagination',
        slidesPerView: 5,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        freeMode: true,
        keyboardControl: false,
    });
  });
</script>
```

I don't want the margin.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

How do I change the colour blue on the arrow to **black**?

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
    background-color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    right:10px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #000 !important;
    fill: black !important;
    stroke: black !important;
}
```

Does not work of course!

Comment: The element `.swiper-button-next` is set to `right:10px`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I don't want the margin. Any ideas?"*

If the margin is **really the margin**, not the result of `right` property, try to overwrite default "swipers" styles using `!important`, like this:

```
.class {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Otherwise set `right` property to `0`:

```
.class {
  right: 0;
}
```

Or

```
.class {
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

If it doesn't work without `!important`.

---

*"How do I change the colour blue on the arrow to black?"*

If you just want to make them black, you can simply use one of the built-in classes (`swiper-button-black` in your case) - thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1280#issuecomment-253364082).

Comment: it works now. I have another question - how do I change the colour on the arrow to black?

Comment: @teelou, what this arrows actually are? SVG, font icon, or pure css element?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.

Comment: can't find any info on their doc.

Comment: @teelou, just open "developer tools" (f12 in most cases) and inspect the element. Or press mouse2 on the element and click "inspect"

Comment: this is what I get `<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-arrow hide-for-small-only hide-for-medium-only" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"></div>` from the dev tool.

Comment: I just looked at your reputation and thought, that you know about devtools without my instructions)

Comment: found it. it is svg but have no idea how to change its colour: `.swiper-button-next, .swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%…2L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}`

Comment: @teelou, i really have no idea what this arrow is, so try to change `fill`, `stroke`, `color` and `background-color` to any color you like with `!important` flag after it, i hope one of these will work. If not, check the docs, if there is a way to style it, it should be in the docs. If not, so there is no way to do that or i don't know the one.

Comment: @teelou, if it's an SVG, `fill` or `stroke` should work

Comment: I have tried it. but dunno where should I apply the fill and stroke. see my edit above please. thanks.

Comment: @teelou, does elements with styles `.swiper-button-next` and `.swiper-button-prev` has any other elements inside it?

Comment: Found the answer - `swiper-button-black`. I think they are hardcoded the svg `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%23007aff'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E`

Comment: @teelou, the last thing that i can suggest is to try to use `​path {fill: black !important;}`​. If this will not work, sorry, i have no idea how to do that =( Or it's really impossible, to change their color.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think I will just use what they provided `swiper-button-black` - less pain customising it lol

Comment: @teelou, glad to help, a little pity that we didn't find working solution for customizing

Answer (score 53):

Add this to style the prev / next arrows:

```
.swiper-button-prev {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M0%2C22L22%2C0l2.1%2C2.1L4.2%2C22l19.9%2C19.9L22%2C44L0%2C22L0%2C22L0%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%234c71ae'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%2027%2044'%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M27%2C22L27%2C22L5%2C44l-2.1-2.1L22.8%2C22L2.9%2C2.1L5%2C0L27%2C22L27%2C22z'%20fill%3D'%234c71ae'%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") !important;
}
```

Where "4c71ae" is the color you want to use in HEX.

Comment: I find David's answer easier if it's just about changing color https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381871/swiper-how-to-customise-arrow-buttons#answer-61428906

Answer (score 26):

```
:root {
    --swiper-theme-color: #000;
}
```

Try this instead of !important to change color.

Answer (score 18):

Those who want to change the default arrows just set you custom SVG etc in the elements the HTML; mine is next & prev

```html
<div class="swiper-button-next">Next</div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev">Prev</div>
```

And remove the default icons in CSS

```css
.swiper-button-next::after, .swiper-button-prev::after {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution and I cannot believe that I didn't even think that I can just add a custom value in the div

Answer (score 13):

With the current version of SwiperJS (v.5.3.8) you can change the color of the arrows in css without any issues. Just define color.

```
.swiper-button-prev {
    color: red; 
}

.swiper-button-next {
    color: #000; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking to change the color etc of various buttons etc for Swiper, be sure to inspect the CSS of what you are trying to change and see if the property you are trying to change is using a CSS variable.

In the case were a CSS variable has been used, you need to re-define it in order to change it.

Example for changing the color of the swiper next/prev buttons:

**Underlying CSS:**

```
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: calc(var(--swiper-navigation-size)/ 44 * 27);
    height: var(--swiper-navigation-size);
    margin-top: calc(0px - (var(--swiper-navigation-size)/ 2));
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--swiper-navigation-color,var(--swiper-theme-color));
}
```

**Add this to the styles.css (or globals.css in NextJS)**

```
:root {
  --swiper-navigation-color: #E49A38;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use JavaScript, you can also change `--swiper-navigation-color` inside the page/component instead of changing `:root` in the CSS file. I found it more convenient in React/Next.js. Just add this to your code.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--swiper-theme-color", "#000")
```

If you are going with this solution and you are building a React/Next.js app, remember to include the code from above in useEffect to load the `document` in the appropriate moment (more about it [here](https://dev.to/typicoul/fixing-next-js-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined-2jgi)).

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--swiper-theme-color", "#000")
 }, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React, another approach apart from @Jakub’s is to pass a `style` prop to `Swiper` like this

```
<Swiper style={{"--swiper-navigation-color": "#FFF", "--swiper-pagination-color": "#FFF"}}>
 .....
</Swiper>
```

This works perfectly except with Typescript (in production). You get an error that is silent in development but stops the app from deploying successfully (on Vercel in my case). The workaround is to remove the style props as done above, and target the elements we need to style (pagination indicators, next-button, prev-button etc) in our CSS WITH MORE SPEICIFITY, so as to override the default styles from Swiper. For example:

```
html.dark .swiper-button-prev, html.dark .swiper-button-next{
    color: #63fb9a;
}

html .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    background: #05d652e8;
}

html.dark .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    background: #63fb9a;
}

html .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background: #05d652e8;
}

html.dark .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    background: #63fb9a;
}

html .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active, html.dark .swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

html .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

html .swiper-navigation-size {
    width: calc(35/ 44 * 27);
    height: 35;
    margin-top: calc(0px - (35/ 2));

}
```

I did `html.dark` above just to illustrate a case where you're using Tailwind CSS and need a dark mode variant of your styles.

Also, `!important` will override the styles too, but it's considered as a bad practice unless the usage is VERY IMPORTANT.

Comment: I think you have a typo:
you typed "--swiper-navigation-color" twice when you probably wanted to refer to "--swiper-pagination-color"

Comment: Oh thanks for spotting that, George! Will edit now

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Angular**, you can simply use `::ng-deep` to **override** the color.

For example :

```
::ng-deep .swiper-button-prev,
::ng-deep .swiper-button-next {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.swiper-button-next::after, .swiper-button-prev::after{
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

For those seeking to substitute default arrows with customized SVG icons, the Swiper version utilized is `8.3.2`.

Here is a [demo example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-swiper-api-y6hkkn?file=src/components/MySlides.vue) project.

Place `<img>` tag into both elements.

```
<!-- Navigation arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-prev">
  <img src="@/assets/icons/svg/right-arrow.svg" />
</div>
<div class="swiper-button-next">
  <img src="@/assets/icons/svg/right-arrow.svg" />
</div>
```

Then, remove the default icons in CSS.

```
.swiper-button-prev::after,
.swiper-button-next::after {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-button-prev img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.swiper-button-next {
  --swiper-navigation-color:white;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  --swiper-navigation-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Yes, put the code in the snippets in your css file then instead of white put black.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make them white or black you can use the built-in classes.

```
<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-black"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:root {
    --swiper-theme-color: #B9FF66 !important;
}

.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28rem !important;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
    left: 18rem !important;
    background-image: url("/images/arrow-left.svg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper-button-next {
    right: 18rem !important;
    background-image: url("/images/arrow-right.svg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* remove default icons */

.swiper-button-next::after, .swiper-button-prev::after {
    content: "";
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 375px) {
    .swiper-button-prev {
        left: 15.5rem !important;
    }

    .swiper-button-next {
        right: 15.5rem !important;
    }
}
```

I changed the arrow icon and set the default theme to a different color than the default, adjust the values according to your preference.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using swiper with vanilla javascript you can just change the root colors in your main css file.

```
    :root {

  /* navigation arrows */
  --swiper-navigation-color: black;

  /* pagination buttons */
  --swiper-pagination-color: black;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: black;
}
```

Also you can check the [style docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#styles) for other style properties

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
.main__swiper_left {
background-image: url("../img_2/main__swiper_left.png");
width: 58px;
height: 58px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}

.main__swiper_left::after {
display: none;
}
```

[Source](https://dev.to/timo_ernst/how-to-customize-prev-next-buttons-in-react-swiper-js-4lki)

Comment: Please correctly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the color, edit the swiper-bundle.min.css on line 13, change the :root attribute to this:

```
    :root {
     --swiper-theme-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
// use the `useState` hook instead of `useRef`
const [prevEl, setPrevEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
const [nextEl, setPrevEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null)
<Swiper navigation={{ prevEl, nextEl }}>
// some slides
</Swiper>
<div ref={(node) => setPrevEl(node)}>prev</div>
<div ref={(node) => setNextEl(node)}>next</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.swiper.swiper-button-next {color: black; --swiper-navigation-size: 30px;}

.swiper.swiper-button-prev{color: black; --swiper-navigation-size: 30px;}
```

Try this one! to Increase and Decrease Size and Change Color.
Don't forget to use `!important` after the color property.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to customize these arrows. You just need to specify your proper parameters in the :root of your CSS file.

```
:root {
--swiper-navigation-size: 16px; /* To edit the size of the arrows */
--swiper-navigation-color: #000; /* To edit the color of the arrows */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I did is removing 'navigation' from config options and instead created new html btn element with my own custom styling,after that I added slideNext() and slidePrev() methods of the Swiper instance.

```
const swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      keyboardControl: true,

    });
    const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-and-prev-buttons .next');
    const prevButton = document.querySelector('.next-and-prev-buttons .prev');

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      swiper.slideNext();
    });

    prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      swiper.slidePrev();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Swipper inside WordPress and couldn't figure out why a blue margin was appearing in my swipper buttons:

[image: Swipper next button with blue margin]

Using the browser inspector I noticed that the blue arrow is a svg element loaded in the background attribute so the following CSS rules fixed it for me:

```css
.swiper-button-prev {
    background: none;
    color: black !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
    background: none;
    color: black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking at this answer in 2023 using a swiper web component in React and who wants to hide the default nav svg arrows. I managed to do so by injecting these styles in:

```css
:host .swiper-button-prev > svg,
:host .swiper-button-next > svg {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With https://swiperjs.com/element Web Components in React you can target the shadow DOM with `::part`.  To implement a circular background for the buttons, for example (SCSS):

```
    swiper-container {
        &::part(button-next), &::part(button-prev) {
            padding:10px 15px;
            border-radius:50%;
            background-color: #ffffff80; 

        }
        &:hover {
            background-color: white;
        }
    }
```

combined with:

```
<swiper-container 
          style={{
            "--swiper-navigation-color": "#000",
            "--swiper-navigation-size": "25px",       
          }}
> ...
</swiper-container>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.swiper-button-prev {
    color: green !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
    color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the color, you can simply do the following and it will overwrite the current color to white... Hope this will be useful!
Note: You can specify any color you want to change! Thanks

```
.swiper-button-prev,.swiper-button-next{ 
   color:white !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**This worked for me.**

```
.swiper-button-prev {
    color: red !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).